# Internet connection in windows after installing bootcamp

Tags: bootcamp

After installing bootcamp on my MacBook, I installed Windows 7. Everything seems to work on the Windows side except for the internet. I have tried with an ethernet cable as well as wireless connection. The wireless connection works fine on the OS X side. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the BootCamp drivers? You can download them using BootCamp assistant in Mac OS X. Installing them should fix up the network issue right up. All you need to do to is burn them to a CD and load it up in Windows.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: or USB key is fine, even for Superdrive machines